# Why do I get "the receiver expression should be replaced with the type qualifier"?

Tags: java, process

```
$ javac Main.java 
    Main.java:27: error: illegal static interface method call
        ProcessHandle.current().allProcesses().mapToLong(w->w.pid()).forEach(System.out::println);
                                            ^
      the receiver expression should be replaced with the type qualifier 'ProcessHandle'
    1 error
```

Why do I get "the receiver expression should be replaced with the type qualifier 'ProcessHandle'"?

What shall I do instead? Thanks.

---

```
import java.lang.System;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("visible processes pids are: ");
    ProcessHandle.current().allProcesses().mapToLong(w->w.pid()).forEach(System.out::println);  

    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide full java code. i can't say anything basis on this error.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: You cannot override static methods, but you can hide static methods/members.

Comment: Here you're trying to override ProcessHandle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are You trying to achieve here? It doesn't seem to make much sense to ask for the current ProcessHandle and then use that to query allProcesses. Both of these are static methods. You probably want to just omit the ".current()".